# Applescript - easy script to take pictures OUT of folder at bulk

Tags: automation, applescript, osx-mountain-lion

i need a simple generic script [which works on folder opened in finder] that will extract all files from folders while keeping folders alive.

Ie. i have 10 folders and each has 1 file inside. **After running script id like to have in same place 10 files and 10 empty folders.**

I had some tries with applescript but somehow failed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set mainFolder to (choose folder)
tell application "Finder"
    set theFiles to files of (entire contents of mainFolder)
    move theFiles to mainFolder
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use mv or find:

```
cd ~/Folder; mv */* .
cd ~/Folder; find . -type f -exec mv {} . \;
```